# Magento 2: how to send ajax request in knockout js?

Tags: magento2, ajax, knockoutjs

We have one button on checkout page to find address from our

API. We want to send one ajax request to that API to get some data.

How do we send ajax request from knockout js?

Comment: could you specify the step where you are using this button.

Answer (score 7):

Use **mage/storage** for ajax call in knockoutjs

```
define(
    [
        ...
        'mage/storage'
        ...
    ],
    function(
        ...
        storage
        ...
    ) {

        return Component.extend({
            ...

            /** Your function for ajax call */
            myAjaxCall: function(dataToPass) {

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                storage.post(
                    'url/of/mycontroller',
                    JSON.stringify(dataToPass),
                    true
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        /** Do your code here */
                        alert('Success');
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: How to pass data and retrieve data in controller can you please explain

Comment: How can i get that data in knockout js bindng returning by this function? my ajax response i returning a string but when i use data-bind="text: myAjaxCall()" instead of printing the stirng, it print object Object. when i debug it by dumping the value of object in console.log, i can see it has the key ResponseJSON which has the string value. but i cant get it.

Comment: Hello Prince. Do you know about which method use as beforeSend() in storage.post() ?

Comment: How to get post data in controller while using storage ajax call?

Comment: Getting this error: cabinet.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')