# How to send data from html template to controller magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, knockoutjs, data, request

My controller is calling but how to send data and retrieve data?

My template:

```
<!-- ko -->
<tr class="totals fee excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <form data-role="save" data-bind="submit:save" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="spendpoints" id="spendpoints"
                   data-bind="text: getValue()" value="20"/>
            <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

My js:

```
define(
    [
        'Company_Module/js/view/checkout/summary/fee',
        'mage/storage',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (Component, storage) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            /** Your function for ajax call */
            save: function (data) {

                // fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                storage.post(
                    'custom/spendpoints/index',
                    JSON.stringify(data),
                    true
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        /** Do your code here */
                        alert('Success--' + data);

                        // fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        // fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
                // return data;
            },
            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

My controller:

```
<?php 
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Spendpoints; 
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
protected $_pageFactory;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
)
{
$this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
$this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/spendpoints.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$request = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

$logger->info('spendpointsdata'.print_r($request));

$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__(' My Reward Points '));
$this->_view->renderLayout();
} 
}
```

**PS:** I followed this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/175850/55981

Comment: Maybe try to $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

Comment: ok, let me check

Comment: i tried but no use it returning "1"

Comment: Do you send the correct data to controller? use console.log in js file to check the data

Comment: Why using js? You want ajax? Or you want store the informations in local storage if not use a simple form with action and post method

Comment: i just want to send text fiel value from html template to controller any method ajax (or) js @MohamedElMrabet

Comment: See mu answer its just a simple post

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the Magento\Customer module to see an example of how this works.

`\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\authentication.html` is the knockout template.

The form submit handler is in `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\authentication.js` and look like this:

```
/**
 * Provide login action.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} loginForm
 */
login: function (loginForm) {
    var loginData = {},
        formDataArray = $(loginForm).serializeArray();

    formDataArray.forEach(function (entry) {
        loginData[entry.name] = entry.value;
    });

    if ($(loginForm).validation() &&
        $(loginForm).validation('isValid')
    ) {
        fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
        loginAction(loginData, checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl, undefined, messageContainer).always(function () {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        });
    }
}
```

The `loginAction` function is contained in:
`\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\web\js\action\login.js`. Here it is:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} loginData
 * @param {String} redirectUrl
 * @param {*} isGlobal
 * @param {Object} messageContainer
 */
action = function (loginData, redirectUrl, isGlobal, messageContainer) {
    messageContainer = messageContainer || globalMessageList;

    return storage.post(
        'customer/ajax/login',
        JSON.stringify(loginData),
        isGlobal
    ).done(function (response) {
        if (response.errors) {
            messageContainer.addErrorMessage(response);
            callbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
                callback(loginData);
            });
        } else {
            callbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
                callback(loginData);
            });
            customerData.invalidate(['customer']);

            if (redirectUrl) {
                window.location.href = redirectUrl;
            } else if (response.redirectUrl) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
            } else {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        messageContainer.addErrorMessage({
            'message': 'Could not authenticate. Please try again later'
        });
        callbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
            callback(loginData);
        });
    });
};
```

And the controller that receives the data is this:
`\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Ajax\Login.php`:

```
public function execute()
{
    $credentials = null;
    $httpBadRequestCode = 400;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    try {
        $credentials = $this->helper->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $resultRaw->setHttpResponseCode($httpBadRequestCode);
    }
    if (!$credentials || $this->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'POST' || !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $resultRaw->setHttpResponseCode($httpBadRequestCode);
    }

    $response = [
        'errors' => false,
        'message' => __('Login successful.')
    ];
    try {
        $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate(
            $credentials['username'],
            $credentials['password']
        );
        $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $this->customerSession->regenerateId();
        $redirectRoute = $this->getAccountRedirect()->getRedirectCookie();
        if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectRoute) {
            $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_redirect->success($redirectRoute);
            $this->getAccountRedirect()->clearRedirectCookie();
        }
    } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
        $response = [
            'errors' => true,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
    } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
        $response = [
            'errors' => true,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $response = [
            'errors' => true,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = [
            'errors' => true,
            'message' => __('Invalid login or password.')
        ];
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    return $resultJson->setData($response);
}
```

Looking at this controller, we can see that it uses `$credentials = $this->helper->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getContent());` to get the request data, so I suggest you try that.

Answer (score 1):

If "my controller" is a full code then you are not returning a bit back with response. Add return statement

First of all inject jsonResponseFactory:

```
public function __construct(
    .....

    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ...
) {
   ....
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

    parent::__construct(
)
```

And then in execute method:

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

$result->setData(['data' => $request]);
return $result;
```

Comment: i want to get data in controller

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <?php  
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
    $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
    $url = $urlInterface->getUrl("module/spendpoints/index");
   ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="spendpoints" id="spendpoints" value="20"/>
        <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
    </form>
```

And in your controller you try this

```
   public function execute() {
      $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
      print_r($request);
   }
```

Comment: it's redirecting to 404 it's adding URL_TO_CONTROLER to current url

Comment: Replace URL_TO_CONTROLER by url of you controller can you show me the path of your controller

Comment: path to controller – module/spendpoints/index

Comment: See now my update

Comment: that's .html file

Comment: Ok what the path of your html file?  its a knockout template? if yes what js load this template

Comment: /view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/fee.html

/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee.js

Comment: I can't find this js file can you tell me the module?

Comment: it's a custom module from https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186023/55981