# how to call ajax request in knockout js?

Tags: magento2

I have button on checkout page with knowckout js to find pincodes with my API. Now I want to send one ajax request to that API.

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component
    ) {
        'use strict';

        $(document).on('click', '.common-place-order', function (event) {

        });
    }
);
```

So how do we call ajax request from knockout js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **mage/storage** for ajax call in knockoutjs

You final code look like this:

```
define(
[
  'jquery',
  'ko',
  'uiComponent',
  'mage/storage'
],
 function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component,
        storage
    ) {
        'use strict';

        $(document).on('click', '.common-place-order', function (event) {
            /** Your function for ajax call */
            myAjaxCall: function(dataToPass) {
                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                storage.post(
                    'url/of/mycontroller',
                    JSON.stringify(dataToPass),
                    true
                ).done(
                  
                ));
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, how can i retrieve those value returned by the function in knockout JS binding ?

I was trying to use this  

myAjaxCall: function(dataToPass) {
            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
            return storage.post(
                'url/of/mycontroller',
                JSON.stringify(dataToPass),
                true
            ).done( response

            ));
        }

but instead of returning the response it return the whole javascript object.

Answer (score 3):

> Try to use bellow code

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component
    ) {
        'use strict';

        $(document).on('click', '.common-place-order', function (event) {
        var YOUR_URL_HERE = your_ajax_url;
            var param = 'ajax=1';
                $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: YOUR_URL_HERE,
                    data: param,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        });
    }
);
```

you can also use mage/storage for ajax call in knockoutjs [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175843/magento-2-how-to-send-ajax-request-in-knockout-js)